# convert string "12345678912345678" to int in React > v16

Tags: reactjs

In React if the string is small like "1234" all is OK. However if we have long string like "123456789123456789" I get error. 
I am using ParseInt() function to convert my string to Int and I get an exception. How to fix this?

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: can you please add log

Comment: there is no such thing as `ParseInt`, it's `parseInt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That number won't fit into an int. Your best bet is to use bignumber.js: https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/

Note that this will return an **array** of numbers, if you want numbers of arbitrary length, use [big-integer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer).

**EDIT**: for others who are curious, an int is 32 bits. This means that you can only store numbers up to `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111` in binary, which is (signed) `2147483647` or (unsigned) `4294967295`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use default parseInt() of javascript

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt